# How to generate a sequential number that restarts yearly in a web application

Tags: php, sqlite

I need to generate a code which consists of some arbitrary prefix, a year, and an incrementing number. The incrementing number must start at 1 at the first time when the number is generated that year.

This code needs to be added to the sqlite database and be available elsewhere in the PHP script.

What i have done now uses 4 accesses to the database:

```
    $codePrefix = 'TEST';
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO test (year)
         VALUES(strftime("%Y", "now"))'
    );
    
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $id = $db->lastInsertId();
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `year` FROM `test` WHERE `id`=:id');
    
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $year = $result['year'];
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Ifnull(Max(id), 0) `max_id` FROM `test`
     WHERE `year`<:year');
    
    $stmt->bindValue(':year', $year);
    
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $previousMax = $result['max_id'];
    
    $codeSuffix = $id-$previousMax;
    
    $code = "{$codePrefix}-{$year}-{$codeSuffix}";
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE `test` SET `code`=:code WHERE `id`=:id');
    
    $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    
    $stmt->execute();
```

Here i am abusing the fact that the `id` is an integer primary key, and autoincrements.

This works. But i feel that it is doing something very easy in a very complicated manner.

Is there a better solution? I need to assume that the midnight of the first of January can happen at any moment of the code, so i cannot do things like get the year information from PHP without hitting the database.

Before somebody asks, the reason i am using prepared statements even when no values are bound is because late on obviously more data will be inserted into the table.

Comment: No one is going to fault you for always using prepared statements! Almost every time I see this requirement for sequential patterns with either no gaps or that repeat with a prefix, it is to solve a display or output problem, and doesn’t and shouldn’t be handled directly by the database. The first item in the database of the year is just the result of a query and it can be called `1` without needing to store that. So before you peruse this too far, I’d really double check that you actually need this.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I am sure that i need it. The code is actually what i need, rather than needing the code to solve another problem. This is not in regards to an output problem (it didn't even occur to me).

Comment: @ChrisHaas Gaps will make me upset, but if they exist very rarely, i would accept them as a fact of life. In the way i have implemented it, gaps will only appear if a manual deletion of an entry will occur. I can definitely live with that.

Comment: Could you do `{$prefix}-{$year}-{$dayOfYear}-{$num}` where `num` is an integer but isn't necessarily continuous? I.e., just use a unix timestamp and then you can generate the id on insert.

Comment: Note also, if you base the next record's ID on the results of a SELECT of the last record, then you're introducing the possibility of duplicate IDs as soon as more than one thread is running.

Comment: @AlexHowansky No, using the day is not an option. The format needs to be as i have described. Also i did not do a select of the last id, i have used `lastInsertId()` to get the id i have just inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a pure SQL solution using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function. Below assigns to new field, *new_id*:

```sql
UPDATE test
SET new_id = 'TEST_' || test.[Year] || '_' || sub.rn
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        [Year],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year] ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM test
) AS sub
WHERE test.id = sub.id;
```

Comment: I really do like this, have just given it a test, and it would cut the number of database accesses to 3, to insert the initial data, to update, and then to select the code (what you called `new_id`). If nothing better will be here, i will accept this as the answer.

Comment: A small note, `Year` column is ambiguous in the first context it is used. And of course i will `WHERE test.id=:id AND sub.id=:id` because i will not want to overwrite previously generated codes.

Comment: Consider adding a new text column for *newid* that regularly updates and avoid PHP parameters. This window calc can return different results if rows are deleted or years change. So, run after every appended row. BTW - SQLite always maintains unique `rowid` system variable on tables.

Comment: Also, not sure what you mean by *Year* being ambiguous since your very question is asking to sequential numbering by year. If this is calculated replace accordingly. So you may have to adjust to suit your needs.

Comment: It should be `SET new_id = 'TEST_' || test.[Year] || '_' || sub.rn`

Comment: It would be a no-go for me if the values of previous entries will be destroyed. The suffix is arbitrary and will not be the same for all entries.

Comment: No, still if it will break previous entries, because their prefix will almost always be different, it is a no-go. But like i have said with a different `WHERE` it works.

Comment: Yeah, `ROW_NUMBER` will run on existing records. So if any past record is deleted (or year changes) all row numbers *after* its position in its corresponding year will be recalculated. I wish you explain your use case (or X of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)) since users should not be assigning unique identifiers given the transactional nature of database records. Arguably, such ids should not be visible in applications!